# Expanding Panel on click to view hidden controls

Tags: c#, wpf, gui-design

I am currently working on a C# wpf project. What I was looking for is a GUI control that can have other GUI controls inside but are hidden and when the user clicks on the GUI control it then expands the panel to reveal the hidden GUI components. I have seen other programs but I can't find anything like that in C#.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `<Expander ... />`  control.

[This tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) has a few pictures.